# cmd give com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt erro

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-notifications, react-native-firebase, react-native-fcm

I want to use `react-native-fcm` for google firebase push notification but when I run `react-native run-android` it gives me this error 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

my react native version :
"react-native": "0.55.4"
fcm version :
"react-native-fcm": "^15.0.2"

android => bulde.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

android/app=>buld.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'Notif'
include ':react-native-fcm'
project(':react-native-fcm').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fcm/android')

include ':app'
```

I've linked google-services.json in android/app folder

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: AAPT is process name, it has some error along with it. Can you post full logcat?

Comment: First of all, Change this   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'` in your `android/app=>buld.gradle`